# .NET Web API Project as a Worker

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, backgroundworker

A bit new with .Net, I'm using .Net core 5.
I have a Web API project which listens to requests.
I want this project to call another API once in a while -
one call as the project starts, and then, another 2 calls every 5 seconds.
It seems like my rest api project now has to act like a Worker project.
Can I do it ? Can I add a schedular process somewhere on the start up of the project ?
Thanks !

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed quite easy to do with an existing Web APi project:

1. Add your worker as a class like

   ```
    public class Worker : BackgroundService  
    {  
        public Worker()
        {
            // Maybe inject services if you need something here
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await this.MakeCall();
                await Task.Delay(1000 * 5, stoppingToken);
            }
        }

        private async Task MakeCall()
        {
            // Call your other service here
        }
    }
   ```
2. Register your worker as a hosted service, which will make it run. Add this to your startup's `ConfigureServices` method:

   ```
   services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
   ```

And there's your worker service. You can now override other methods from `BackgroundService`, for example to do something on startup and shutdown.